# Django Channel Group send then discard

Tags: django, django-channels

I want to send a message to a Group and immediately afterwards discard one of the reply channels.

It doesn't work due to the consumer_finished signal not sending until the incoming message is fully dealt with, I gather from debugging the code and witnessing when the message is sent to the frontend.

The result is that my message doesn't get sent on the channel that I delete afterwards.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a Channel bug/feature?

```
    Group(room_id).send({'text': json.dumps({'command': 'leave', 'room': {'id': room_id}, 'user': {'id': str(message.user.id)}})})
    Group(room_id).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the send method has an 'immediately' parameter. That worked.